# parsing a text file in python, c++, given specific format

Tags: python, c++, file, parsing

I have a file in the following format; I would like to parse it in pyhton and c++ and extract the number after ImpVarNo:
There are lots of line in this format.

sample.txt

```
Start:
abc pqr
(FF_GGGGG_CONFIRM_TR):TC:20222,SeqNum:86,ImpVarNo:1000000008234436,Id:12,oneId:66454,a/c:1,ImpValue:905,Impvar:25,actualValue:905,actualVar:25,abc pqr xyz
Impquantity:0,pgb ncr yepp
Start:
abc pqr
(FF_GGGGG_CONFIRM_TR):TC:20222,SeqNum:86,ImpVarNo:1000000008234436,Id:12,oneId:66454,a/c:1,ImpValue:905,Impvar:25,actualValue:905,actualVar:25,abc pqr xyz
Impquantity:0,pgb ncr yepp
Start:
abc pqr
(FF_GGGGG_CONFIRM_TR):TC:20222,SeqNum:86,ImpVarNo:1000000008234436,Id:12,oneId:66454,a/c:1,ImpValue:905,Impvar:25,actualValue:905,actualVar:25,abc pqr xyz
Impquantity:0,pgb ncr yepp
Start:
abc pqr
(FF_GGGGG_CONFIRM_TR):TC:20222,SeqNum:86,ImpVarNo:1000000008234436,Id:12,oneId:66454,a/c:1,ImpValue:905,Impvar:25,actualValue:905,actualVar:25,abc pqr xyz
Impquantity:0,pgb ncr yepp
```

So I wrote the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re

hand = open('newlogfile.txt')
for line in hand:
    r = re.compile("ExOrderNo:(\d+),") 
    print r
```

Comment: You could use a regular expression in both Python and C++11.

Comment: Choose a language, also show your effort, SO is not a code writing service

Comment: `r = re.compile("ImpVarNo:(\d+),")`

Comment: How will I print the number parsed after "ImpVarNo:"; what would the 'r'. sorry still trying to figure it out. couldn't find good example on code. see the edit/ @PadraicCunningham

Comment: `i = r.findall(line);if i:print(i)`

Comment: why there is a need of "if i" condition I always have some value after ImpVarNo: ; also when I printed it without the "if i" condition it printed: blank values too but I always something filled up after "ImpVarNo:number" in the file. @PadraicCunningham

Comment: Because you parse line by line not the whole file at once

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
with  open('newlogfile.txt') as f:
    r = re.compile("ImpVarNo:(\d+),")
    for line in f:
        inp = r.findall(line)
        if inp:
            print(float(inp[0]))

1000000008234436
1000000008234436
1000000008234436
1000000008234436
```

If the line always starts with the same thing:

```
   import re
    with  open('newlogfile.txt') as f:
        r = re.compile("ImpVarNo:(\d+),")
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith("(FF_GGGGG_CONFIRM_TR)"):
                print(r.findall(line))
```

Comment: Kindly check the added code for hits. There is another file which has ImpVarNo. written one value in one line and then there is the i which we have calculated. it doesn't print any hits ? is there any better way to do it in python ?

Comment: also it contains values in the following format: ['1000000002396045'] I just want it to contain 1000000002396045 so that it can be compared.

Comment: If you used my code you would not be seeing  `['1000000002396045']` `print(float(r.findall(line)[0]))`

Comment: Also repeatedly changing your question is not very helpful f you have a new question then as a new question.

Answer (score -2):

However this is most trivial approach, You can use `RegEx` to make your code cleaner.

```
sample_file = open(sample.txt)
contents = sample_file.readlines()
for line in contents:
    if line.startswith("(FF_GGGGG_CONFIRM_TR)"):
        number_after_impvarno = int(line.split(",")[2][9:])
```